# QList <QString> и QDataStream

Tags: qt

Пытаюсь в QDataStream записать QList а потом извлечь его.

```
QList <QString> l = {"a", "bb", "ccc"};
qDebug() << l;
QByteArray arr;
QDataStream in(&arr, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
in.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_DefaultCompiledVersion);
in << l;
QList <QString> l2;
QDataStream out(&arr, QIODevice::ReadOnly);
out >> l2;
qDebug() << l2;
```

На выходе пусто. Почему?

Comment: Если использовать QStringList то все ОК, но QStringList это по сути QList <QString>

Comment: попробуйте в самое начало добавить: qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators<QList<QString>>("QList<QString>");У меня Ваш пример кода работает корректно.

Comment: Работает. Теперь объясните в чем фишка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того чтоб отправлять в поток пользовательские типы данных необходимо:
1.определить оператор ввода и вывода. Это можно по простому:

```
friend QDataStream &operator <<(QDataStream &in, const MyClass &_obj)
{
    in << _obj.m_field1;
    in << _obj.m_field2;
    in << _obj.m_field3;
    in << _obj.m_field4;
    return in;
}

friend QDataStream &operator >>(QDataStream &out, MyClass &_obj)
{
    out >> _obj.m_field1;
    out >> _obj.m_field2;
    out >> _obj.m_field3;
    out >> _obj.m_field4;
    return out;
}
```

Правда тут есть минус, если мы решили добавить еще одно поле, то записанные ранее данные нельзя будет прочитать. То есть, отсутствует обратная совместимость. Для того чтоб это избежать, можно использовать более сложный вариант:

```
friend QDataStream &operator <<(QDataStream &in, const MyClass &_obj)
{
    QVariantMap m;
    m["field1"] = QVariant::fromValue(_obj.m_field1);
    m["field2"] = QVariant::fromValue(_obj.m_field2);
    m["field3"] = QVariant::fromValue(_obj.m_field3);
    m["field4"] = QVariant::fromValue(_obj.m_field4);
    in << m;
    return in;
}

friend QDataStream &operator >>(QDataStream &out, MyClass &_obj)
{
    QVariantMap m;
    out >> m;
    _obj.m_field1 = m["field1"].toInt();
    _obj.m_field2 = m["field2"].toString();
    _obj.m_field3 = m["field3"].toDouble();
    _obj.m_field4 = m["field4"].toBool();
    return out;
}
```

Или даже немного упростить:

```
template <class T>
static void convert(const QVariant &_val, T &result)
{
    result = _val.value<T>();
}

friend QDataStream &operator >>(QDataStream &out, MyClass &_obj)
{
    QVariantMap m;
    out >> m;
    convert(m["field1"], _obj.m_field1);
    convert(m["field2"], _obj.m_field2);
    convert(m["field3"], _obj.m_field3);
    convert(m["field4"], _obj.m_field4);

    return out;
}
```

В таком случае можно добавлять/удалять поля и все ранее записанные данные можно считать.

2.указать метасистеме qt, что пользовательский тип данных можно писать в поток. Для этого до процесса записи в поток, вызвать функцию:

```
qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators<MyClass>("MyClass");
```

обычно все регистрации делаются сразу после запуска программы.
Если хотим писать в писать список, то так же вызвать:

```
qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators<QList<MyClass>>("QList<MyClass>");
qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators<QVector<MyClass>>("QVector<MyClass>");
```

Если какой-то из членов класса является тоже пользовательским типом, то для него тоже нужно определить функции записи в поток и вызвать qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators

Для базовых Qt типов qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators обычно уже выполнен, так что странно, что у Вас QList< QString > не заработал.

Comment: указывать нужно только в приложении в котором пишется в поток, или также в приложении, в котором читается из потока? Если приложение сетевое

Comment: для QMap <QString, quint16> заработало без регистрации