# Хранение состояния программы в виде набора переменных С++

Tags: c++, архитектура, ini

Есть программный комплекс - написанный на Visual С++: решение состоящее из нескольких проектов, мало друг с другом связанных, но каждый имеющий своё состояние.

Я хотел бы хранить состояния отдельных модулей в конфигах.
Наперёд не знаю сколько и чего будет храниться - просто набор разнотипных элементов string, int, float ...
На данном этапе - предполагаю использовать ini файлы.
(с помощью библиотеки https://github.com/benhoyt/inih)

Мне придётся сначала указывать типы переменных, потом сами переменные, всё это как-то хранить. Но при этом доступ к переменным должен быть быстрым.(Значит надо использовать макросы или инлайн шаблоны...)
Проблема мне представляется достаточно объемной и совершенно точно есть грамотные реализации.

Какие есть готовые библотеки обращения с пользовательскими переменными?

Answer (score 4):

1. Boost.Program_options

   http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/program_options.html
2. `QSettings` из Qt (описание на русском из старой версии - есть новые аналогичные)

   http://doc.crossplatform.ru/qt/4.7.x/qsettings.html

   Запись:

   ```
    QSettings settings("Moose Soft", "Clipper");
    settings.beginGroup("MainWindow");
    settings.setValue("size", size());
    settings.setValue("pos", pos());
    settings.endGroup();
   ```

   Чтение:

   ```
    QSettings settings("Moose Soft", "Clipper");
    settings.beginGroup("MainWindow");
    resize(settings.value("size", QSize(400, 400)).toSize());
    move(settings.value("pos", QPoint(200, 200)).toPoint());
    settings.endGroup();
   ```
3. Возможно есть решения в WinAPI...

Comment: WinAPI не любит большие INI-файлы, если я ничего не путаю. Qt с ними дружит нормально.

Answer (score 1):

Для хранения состояния - создать отдельный класс, в котором будут хранится все необходимые переменные. Перед закрытием программы выполнять метод, который сохраняет все нужные данные в этот класс. После запуска программы, выполнять метод, который на основание данных из класса инициализирует все необходимые значения.

[QList <QString> и QDataStream](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/528333/qlist-qstring-%D0%B8-qdatastream/528338#528338)

Тут описана методика, как с помощью Qt быстро записать/считать состояния этого класса в бинарный файл. Если нужен читаемый конфиг, можно посмотреть в сторону XML.
По личным замерам быстродействия:

1. Бинарная сериализация - 1х времени
2. Бинарная сериализация с использованием QVarianMap - 10x времени
3. Сериализация в XML - 100х времени.

Если нужно записывать-считывать большие объемы данных, лучше использовать первый вариант.

Если не хочется привязываться к Qt, можно записывать классы в Xml, к примеру, используя TinyXml. Примерный алгоритм как здесь https://github.com/sashatref/xmlserializer/tree/master/tinyxmlbased